# How to filter an Array of object with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I understand there are already a lot of similar questions in stack regarding this but i just cant seem to solve mine.
I am looking to filter an array with objects with the condition of another array.

```
const jobPost = [
    {
        id: 1,
        companyName: "Photosnap",
        jobTitle: "Senior Frontend Developer",
        companyLogo: "./photosnap.svg",
        skills: ["Frontend", "Senior", "HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
        new: true,
        featured: true,
        dayOfPost: "1d ago",
        contract: "Full Time",
        region: "USA only"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        companyName: "Manage",
        jobTitle: "Fullstack Developer",
        companyLogo: "./manage.svg",
        skills: ["Fullstack", "Midweight", "Python", "React"],
        new: true,
        featured: true,
        dayOfPost: "1d ago",
        contract: "Part Time",
        region: "Remote"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        companyName: "Account",
        jobTitle: "Junior Frontend Developer",
        companyLogo: "./account.svg",
        skills: ["Frontend", "Junior", "React", "Sass", "JavaScript"],
        new: true,
        featured: false,
        dayOfPost: "2d ago",
        contract: "Part Time",
        region: "USA only"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        companyName: "MyHome",
        jobTitle: "Junior Frontend Developer",
        companyLogo: "./myhome.svg",
        skills: ["Frontend", "Junior", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
        new: false,
        featured: false,
        dayOfPost: "5d ago",
        contract: "Contract",
        region: "USA only"
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        companyName: "Loop Studios",
        jobTitle: "Software Engineer",
        companyLogo: "./loop-studios.svg",
        skills: ["Fullstack", "Midweight", "JavaScript", "Sass", "Ruby"],
        new: false,
        featured: false,
        dayOfPost: "5d ago",
        contract: "Full Time",
        region: "Worldwide"
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        companyName: "FaceIt",
        jobTitle: "Junior Backend Developer",
        companyLogo: "./faceit.svg",
        skills: ["Backend", "Junior", "Ruby", "RoR"],
        new: false,
        featured: false,
        dayOfPost: "2w ago",
        contract: "Full Time",
        region: "UK only"
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        companyName: "Shortly",
        jobTitle: "Junior Developer",
        companyLogo: "./shortly.svg",
        skills: ["Frontend", "Junior", "HTML", "Sass", "JavaScript"],
        new: false,
        featured: false,
        dayOfPost: "2w ago",
        contract: "Full Time",
        region: "Worldwide"
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        companyName: "Insure",
        jobTitle: "Junior Frontend Developer",
        companyLogo: "./insure.svg",
        skills: ["Frontend", "Junior", "Vue", "JavaScript", "Sass" ],
        new: false,
        featured: false,
        dayOfPost: "2w ago",
        contract: "Full Time",
        region: "USA only"
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        companyName: "Eyecam Co.",
        jobTitle: "Full Stack Engineer",
        companyLogo: "./eyecam-co.svg",
        skills: ["Fullstack", "Midweight", "JavaScript", "Django", "Python" ],
        new: false,
        featured: false,
        dayOfPost: "3w ago",
        contract: "Full Time",
        region: "Worldwide"
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        companyName: "The Air Filter Company",
        jobTitle: "Front-end Dev",
        companyLogo: "./the-air-filter-company.svg",
        skills: ["Frontend", "Junior", "React", "Sass", "JavaScript" ],
        new: false,
        featured: false,
        dayOfPost: "1m ago",
        contract: "Part Time",
        region: "Worldwide"
    }
    
]

export default jobPost;
```

The jobpost array is saved in a separate file called jobDB.js and is brought into my app.js by import.

```
import jobDB from "./components/modules/jobDB";



const App = () =>{
const [searchTerms, setSearchTerms] = useState([]); 

const checkCriteria = (data) =>{
   searchTerms.some(term => {
   return data.skills.includes(term);
 })
}

const onClick = (e) => {
    const {textContent} = e.target;
    if (!searchTerms.includes(textContent)){
      setSearchTerms([...searchTerms, textContent])
    }
};

return (
  {searchTerms.length > 0? jobDB.filter(checkCriteria).map(createPost) : 
  jobDB.map(createPost)}
 )

}
```

the searchTerm array is updated upon clicks from the UI but the filtered array always return empty.

Please help! i have been staring at this problem for almost 24 hours.

Comment: upload the code to stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return the actual result for the filter function

```
const checkCriteria = (data) => {
   return searchTerms.some(term => {
     return data.skills.includes(term);
   })
}
```

Comment: Wow. it really is that simple of a solution! i spent a whole day debugging this.. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, a vote or answer marked to this question is appreciated ^^ By the way, debugging is a good practice, it helps you a lot.